# On the optimality of Grover's algorithm by constant factors

Tags: grovers-algorithm

It is well-known that Grover's algorithm is asymptotically optimal. However, is a better algorithm possible by constant factors? And if so, is it known?

Suppose a fixed number of iterations $r$ and ratio $\rho$ of market elements such that, by using the geometric interpretation, the angle does not exceed $\pi/2$ (something like a truncated Grover). For example, for $r = 1$, think in a ratio $\rho \leq 0.25$.

My question is that in such conditions, Grover hits the highest possible probability of measuring a market element (the best amplification) for an quantum algorithm that uses $r$ calls of the oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grover's search is exactly (not just asymptotically) optimal:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9711070